# login issues with mozilla fire fox at the time of report deployment in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i developed one report in ssrs 2008 environment. the url is like below

```
http://test:8080/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReport+Project1%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=excel
```

it is working fine in IE and chrome but in firefox it is asking usename and login .

how can i fix this issue.

kindly don't search for errors in URL

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same problem in the browser .It seems Firefox is not passing the credentials to your SSRS reporting service .You need to enter your SSRS server credentials in the  firefox config file

Check this article out
[how to change reporting service site seurity setting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlreportingservices/thread/2eb3b197-b18b-4b31-a6ab-ba3989e94904)